# How do I run vulkaninfo on login?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I boot up my machine with an intel gpu. When I want to game, I switch to an nvidia gpu. I use vulkan instead of opengl. For some reason vulkan only works by opening a terminal and typing `sudo vulkaninfo` and it's all good to go.

So, I made a `conf` file in `/etc/init` to make it run on startup. Works fine when I boot up with the nvidia gpu. But when I boot up with the intel gpu I have to logout then log back in to switch to nvidia, then open a terminal and type `sudo vulkaninfo` for it to work.

My question is, how can I run `sudo vulkaninfo` when logging in, not just starting up?

I've tried looking for a solution, but all I find are ways to run it on startup (that's how I got the idea for a `conf` file).

P.S. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and I'm a total noob with linux, so please bear with me. Thanks.